# Are Android Intents persisted in disk?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am designing a new app and for security reasons I would like to know if the Intents that we send through the Android OS are ever persisted in disk?

What about sticky intents and their extras?

Comment: Since there is no use of `Intents` that survives a reboot, I would assume that they are not persisted to disk.